Spyder variables do not refresh after restarting kernel
I am running Spyder 5.5.1 on Linux.
After start-up i just create a variable x=1 in the console. x appears correctly on the variable explorer.
Then I restart the kernel (with Ctrl + .).
x still appears on the variable explorer. This looks like a bug to me.
Please please help me.. I love Spyder do not wanna switch to PyCharm!!!
If for example i tick and untick "Exclude private variables" then 'x' disappears from variable explorer.

This seems to be a known bug in Spyder – see the corresponding open issue on GitHub or this (closed) duplicate. At present, there is not much you can do about it other than (a) waiting for the bug to be fixed or (b) helping the Spyder developers to fix the bug.

do you know when this was introduced (i have used 4.0.1 on Win and never had this problem)? are you aware of any workaround?

As to when it was introduced, I have no idea. As to a workaround: for me, closing the corresponding console tab in Spyder rather than restarting the kernel works. However, it might do more than you intend (I usually never use "Restart kernel", so I don't know the exact differences).

that s interesting since i never close the console tab but rather always restart the kernel... they might have similar effects... i ll investigate

I think that's completely normal since different people have different workflows and preferences. To be honest, I rarely use Spyder and usually PyCharm instead.

With Spyder 5 (previous version) I was able to refresh and clean all variables. Since V6 it is impossible.
So I add these lines at the beginning of my code:
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('reset', '-sf')

